# Returning result from async Ajax call via synchronous API

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I have a JavaScript API interface that I have to implement like so:

```
ThirdPartyAPI.GetValue = function (parm)
{
    var result = await getValueViaAjaxFromMyServer(parm);
    return result; // pass the result back to API hook
}
```

I don't control `ThirdPartyAPI.GetValue` except to define the method body.

I understand that to get the return value of the AJAX call, I need to use either a callback, promise or async/await mechanism.  But, since `ThirdPartyAPI.GetValue()` is just a standard synchronous method, is there any trick I can employ to not return the function until my AJAX call completes (other than marking AJAX call synchronous) ?

Comment: It probably just executes. Make that an async function.

Comment: Right, but then the value isn't awaited, right?  Because the caller won't await it.

Comment: It would be awaited, because you assigned it as `async function`. If that is supposed to return an immediate value, that is, of course, going to be a problem. You probably want to use that 3rd Party API method, after your AJAX onload executes.